# Trouble reading a file with fortran90

Tags: fortran

Hi I am a really novice coder and I am trying to read a file of positions in Fortran, but I keep getting severe 59 when I try to run the program. There are 343 rows in the file I am trying to read and 4 columns. I have read many questions that are similar on Stack Overflow but none of them have helped.

I tried the code below, and I expected it to work/let me read the file without errors.

```
PROGRAM force
        implicit none
        integer :: i, j
        real, dimension(343,4) :: a
       
        
        open(1, file='parameters.txt', Status='old', action='read')
        do i = 1,343

                read(1,*)(a(i,j),j=2,4)

        end do
        close(1)
END PROGRAM force
```

This is the file that I'm trying to read (the first 5 rows of it)

```
 Ar   5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        1.00000000000000
 Ar   5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        2.00000000000000
 Ar   5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
 Ar   5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        4.00000000000000
 Ar   5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        5.00000000000000
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. It is important to tag your questions properly und to use the formatting features for code. Always use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old standard revision.

Comment: We also need the exact error message you got. "severe 59" tells nothing useful.

Comment: Hint: Severe errors in Fortran happen when a format specification mismatches the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the 'Ar' item before reading the numbers on each record (line). In list-directed add to the declarations

```
character(len=2) :: col1
```

and change

```
read(1,*) col1,(a(i,j),j=2,4)
```

You can also simplify that to

```
read(1,*) col1,a(i,2:4)
```

(the implicit do was needed in older FORTRAN, but not F90+).

Comment: You might want to set `real, dimension(343,3) :: a` and read with `read(1,*) col1,(a(i,j),j=1,3)` then. No need to keep the first column of `a` only to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading three numbers in each `read` statement. However, the first item on each line is a string. If you know that the numbers start at particular columns, you can use the edit descriptors to read from these columns.

E.g.

```
 read(1,'(tr4,3f22.0)') ...
```

where the actual widths of the columns must be inserted instead of the 22.

`tr4` means move right by 6 columns and then `3f22.0` means read 3 floating point numbers, each from 22 columns.

By the way, using unit numbers, like your `1` lower than than 10 is risky. They may be pre-connected to something else. The most risky are 0,5 and 6, but you never know.